# InnerHTML delay & Marque movement from fixed position

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have customized drop down box with script something like

```
var Text = e.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].innerText;
var Width = e.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].offsetWidth;
var ActWidth = e.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].scrollWidth;
if (ActWidth > Width) 
{
    e.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML = "<marquee>" + Text + "</marquee>";
}
```

But InnerHTML adds delay when mouse over, Can anyone suggest alternative to innerHTML ?

Also any other way morque movement from **fixed position** (beacause when mouse over it shows blank then morque movement) ?